# What is the correct way to reverse a video using java?

Tags: java, file-handling

I wrote a program, reversing a video. But when I tried to open the video file it displayed an error. The file was corrupted. When i tried reversing a text file it worked but video was corrupted. I achieved this by reading the bytes from the file and and storing it into another file in reversed order.
 See code below..

```
// The beginning of the program
    package IO;

import java.io.*;

public class Reverse {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // videoName is the video file to be reversed**
        String videoName = "/Users/Noah/Videos/362f42d24752447aacb3f263c58472ba.mp4";

        // pathName is the output folder path**
        String pathName = "/Users/Noah/Desktop/video file.mp4";
        File vFile = new File(videoName);

        if (vFile.exists()) {
            FileInputStream fIn = null;
            FileOutputStream fOut = null;
            try {
                fIn = new FileInputStream(vFile);
                fOut = new FileOutputStream(pathName);

                int availableData = fIn.available();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[availableData];

                // read all data into buffer**
                int readData = fIn.read(buffer);

                // write data to output folder path in reverse
                // using a countdown**
                if (readData != -1) {
                    for (int i = buffer.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                        fOut.write(buffer[i]);
                        System.out.println('*'); // not necessary
                    }  // end for

                } else System.out.println("The file was not read properly, try again");
                // end if
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (fIn != null && fOut != null) {
                        fIn.close(); // close input stream
                        fOut.close(); // close output stream
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } else System.out.println("File does not exists");
        System.out.println("File read successfully");
    }
}
```

Comment: I would assume it would be because you need to conserve the initial **X** bytes that represent the video header, and only reverse the payload that is the video.

Comment: Do you mean, reverse it so it plays backwards? You'd need to understand the video format.

Comment: @Andy Turner yes i want it to play backwards

Comment: @Jason please i don't understand what you mean by conserving the initial X bytes.

Comment: @user241802 most, if not all, files don't just contain raw bytes that make up the file content. They are also comprised of a bytes of information that tell the decoder  (i.e a media player) how to read the file. I.e the version of the file, the data, the last time it was modified, etctera. Because of this, you can't simply just reverse all bytes and hope it works because now that header information is now at the end of the file. You need to preserve the bytes that make up the header and only reverse the payload (the video itself). Look into this; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_14

Comment: @user241802 reversing a video means putting the frames in the reverse order; this is more like reversing the *words* in a string, not reversing the whole string: "foo bar baz" reverses to "baz bar foo", not "zab rab oof". You need to understand the structure of the data to reverse it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Reversing text in a text file is relatively simplistic.

Dealing with a file format such as a video file is more complex.

There's meta-data in a video file besides just the bits and bytes that compose the video images. Header information, file structure, data compression, etc...

By simply reversing all of the bytes, you've destroyed the file format and made it unreadable.

You need to to study the file format for whatever type of video file you're editing so you can reconstruct the video file into something readable. There may even be a JAVA library somewhere out there that does video reservals.